# how can i notify the adapter that data has been changed/deleted in THIS scenario

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

suppose i have an app that has a tool bar and a fragment container in the main activity, the fragment container in this situation is displaying a fragment that has a recyclerview which has a list of objects retrieved from a basic room database, and the toolbar has a button that clears out all the data stored in the database (which means the code that responsible for this is located in the main activity not in the fragment), how should i go about notifying the adapter inside the fragment that the object list has been updated?
i don't think any code is necessary here as it's more of a general question, but i will gladly share all the code necessary if its needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the adapter a public static variable and call notifyDataSetChanged from the main activity